# Azure Analysis Service, with an on prem gateway, in vnet

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-gateway, vnet

I have the basic tier of Azure Analysis service. I am trying to connect to a Blob storage container that is in the same VNET as the Azure Analysis Service.

I have set up an "on prem gateway" on a VM in the same vnet and am able to connect to the blob storage and pull a test file that is of size 18Bs.

The actual file I want to pull is 85MiB. If I have that file in the same blob container as the previous test file, and try to pull the 85MiB file I get the below error:
*Received error payload from gateway service with ID 320866: With compression algorithm, the compressed data size in a packet exceeds the max ServiceBus limit: GatewayCompressor - CompressedDataSize (11571280) of a non-compressed packet exceeds the maximum payload size of 8500000.*

Is a 85MiB file actually too big for Azure Analysis services??
I read it could be the Gateway API limit (I have seen in AWS is 10mb), can I increase the Gateway API limit?

I am surprised to already reach size limits.